# "Permission denied" with ffmpeg (via snap) on external drive

Tags: permissions, fstab, ffmpeg, external-hdd, snap

I got a new drive and I can copy files fine with simple `cp` on the drive. However for some weird reason I get `Permission denied` with ffmpeg.

Permissions seem fine unless I'm missing something

```
> ll /media/manos/6TB/
drwxrwxrwx  13 manos      4096 Apr 16 00:56  ./
drwxr-x---+  6 manos      4096 Apr 16 00:49  ..
-rwxrwxrwx   1 manos 250900209 Apr 15 17:28  test.mp4*
..
```

But ffmpeg keeps complaing

```
> ffmpeg -i test.mp4 test.mov
ffmpeg version n4.1.4 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 7 (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
  configuration: --prefix= --prefix=/usr --disable-debug --disable-doc --disable-static --enable-avisynth --enable-cuda --enable-cuvid --enable-libdrm --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libass --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore_amrnb --enable-libopencore_amrwb --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-sdl2 --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxcb --enable-libxvid --enable-nonfree --enable-nvenc --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-shared --enable-vaapi --enable-vdpau --enable-version3 --enable-xlib
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
test.mp4: Permission denied
```

Simply copying like below works fine..

```
> cp test.mp4 test.mp4.bak
'test.mp4' -> 'test.mp4.bak'
```

Any ideas on what is going on? This is pretty annoying. Note ffmpeg is installed at `/snap/bin/ffmpeg`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

So after a lot of digging I figured the issue is with snap package manager. Apparently by default, snap can't access the media directory so we need to manually fix this.

Check if ffmpeg has access to `removable-media` like below

```
> snap connections | grep ffmpeg
desktop                   ffmpeg:desktop                             :desktop                          -
home                      ffmpeg:home                                :home                             -
network                   ffmpeg:network                             :network                          -
network-bind              ffmpeg:network-bind                        :network-bind                     -
opengl                    ffmpeg:opengl                              :opengl                           -
optical-drive             ffmpeg:optical-drive                       :optical-drive                    -
pulseaudio                ffmpeg:pulseaudio                          :pulseaudio                       -
wayland                   ffmpeg:wayland                             :wayland                          -
x11                       ffmpeg:x11                                 :x11                              -
```

Add that permission if it's missing

```
sudo snap connect ffmpeg:removable-media
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone googling the permission issue and seeing this thread:

In my case, the problem was that in my code, I didn't close the files had just created in the same method before passing them on to ffmpeg.
So if ffmpeg crashes with `permission denied`, make sure that any open file handles have been closed.

Answer (score 0):

ffmpeg via snap seems to in some kind of snap confinement, where only certain directories are brought into snap.

Currently ( April 2023 ) it's hardcoded that /media and /home/$USER are brought, everything else will not work (think of chroot ).

See more information here: https://askubuntu.com/a/1040278/32777 , especially the comment section

Answer (score -1):

Add `sudo` before your commands. It works for me.

Comment: While this may work it would be a better answer if you could explain why running as root is necessary in this case.