# ffmpeg (via snap) when run with root can't access directories owned by other users

Tags: permissions, ffmpeg, snap

When I run the following command:

```
 /snap/bin/ffmpeg -y -rtsp_transport udp -i 'rtsp://url' -vf scale=1024:-1 -ss 00:00:01 -vframes 1 /home/administrator/camera1/preview.jpg
```

It takes a snapshot of the rtsp stream like intended, the problem is that when I run it as root, I get the following error

```
[image2 @ 0x556426863040] Could not open file : /home/administrator/camera1/preview.jpg
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Input/output error
```

Which is strange because when I had ffmpeg installed using apt I didn't have this issue and because I thought running as root should have permission problems.

I confirmed that this is a problem with file ownership by creating another directory owned by root and didn't run into this problem.

I thought this could be related to [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/580357/permission-denied-with-ffmpeg-via-snap-on-external-drive), but even after I added `ffmpeg:removable-media` snap connection, I didn't notice any changes.

Why is this happening? and what can I do to have it normally (I mean ffmpeg with sudo not having issues writing into other users directories)?

PS.I'm running Ubuntu

Comment: After you invoke a root shell, can you read the file with commands like `cat` or `od` ?

Comment: @SottoVoce Yes to both. the issue seems to be only when it comes to ffmpeg (via snap)